# How to add images to TreeView.Tag?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I add text like this:

```
TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Person");
String[] str = new string[] {"name", "age"};

this.TreeView.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
this.TreeView.Nodes[0].Tag = str;
```

Image in .png extension

Another problem is that all icons in one image, it's like an array :
[image]

How should I grab this icons from this image ?

Comment: Why not use an image editor to put the images in separate files? Also, I can't follow what you are doing with `Tag` here.

Comment: I can separate it, just thought there is other ways

Comment: there are, but they are all unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Then I just need to put the images in the tag, like {"img1", "img2"};

Comment: You mean to store the image objects in an array in the tag? And what will you do with that? Are you trying to set the image for the node?

Answer (score 0):

you could split images with following manner, update code for your needs

For win forms

```
    private List<Image> GetImages(string imageFile)
    {
        var images = new List<Image>();
        Image rootImage = Image.FromFile(imageFile);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Image image = CropImage(rootImage, new Rectangle(10 + i * 60, 0, 70, 60));
            images.Add(image);
        }
        return images;
    }

    private static Image CropImage(Image image, Rectangle area)
    {
        var bmpImage = new Bitmap(image);
        Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(area, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
        return (bmpCrop);
    }
```

for wpf

```
        var image = new Image {Width = 70, Height=60};
        var source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filePath));
        var bitmap = new CroppedBitmap(source, new Int32Rect(0, 0, 70, 60));
        image.Source = bitmap;
```

you could fill tag property after creating images